# How to store coordinates of the screen in Database and how to retrieve all of them when clicked on a button

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app which stores the coordinates of the screen and store it in database and want to retrieve them on a button click

This is my database code

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/20/2016.
 */
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class DataBase
    {
        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_X = "X";
        public static final String KEY_Y = "Y";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Details";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "DetailsTable";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private DbHelper ourHelper;
        private final Context ourContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

        private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public DbHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_X + " TEXT, " + KEY_Y + " TEXT);");
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            }
        }

        public DataBase(Context c) {
            ourContext = c;
        }

        public DataBase open() throws SQLException {
            ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close() {
            ourHelper.close();
        }

        public long createEntry(String x, String y) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_X, x);
            cv.put(KEY_Y, y);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
  public ArrayList<Float> getData() {
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Point p = new Point();
    ArrayList<Float> dataPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] col = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_X, KEY_Y};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, null, null, null, null, null);
    float[] array = new float[c.getCount()];
    float[] array1 = new float[c.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            float x = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("X"));
            p.setX(x);
            dataPoints.add(p.getX());

            float y = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("Y"));
            p.setY(y);
            dataPoints.add(p.getY());
            array[i] = x;
            array1[i] = y;
            i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }


    Log.d("hi", "getData() called");
    return dataPoints;
}
```

this is Point.java

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/20/2016.
 */
public class Point
{

        public float x;
        public float y;
        int id;

        public Point() {}

        public Point(int id, float x, float y) {
            this.id = id;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public Point(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public int getId(){
            return this.id;
        }
        public void setId(int id){
            this.id= id;
        }
        public float getX(){
            return this.x;
        }
        public  void setX(float x){
            this.x=x;
        }
        public float getY(){
            return this.y;
        }
        public void setY(float y){
            this.y=y;
        }
    }
```

this is my main activity

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




        float x = 0, y = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           addTouchListener();

          //  final CanvasView canvas = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.paint_view);



        }
    private  void addTouchListener()
    {
       // TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SQLinfo);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activityView);
        relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {

                 x=event.getX();
                 y=event.getY();

                String text = "You click at x = " + event.getX() + " and y = " + event.getY();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                DataBase entry = new DataBase(MainActivity.this);
                boolean flag = true;
                try {
                    entry.open();
                    entry.createEntry(Float.toString(x), Float.toString(y));
                    entry.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    flag = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } finally {
                    if (flag)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              return false;
        }
    });

        //Setting touch event listener for the PaintView
           Button data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.db);
            data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DbActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });




    }

}
```

and this my Dbactivity.java

```
package com.example.android.touchview;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 7/20/2016.
 */

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DbActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_db);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SQLinfo);
        DataBase db = new DataBase(this);
        try {
            db.open();
            ArrayList<Float> data = db.getData();
            db.close();


            data.toString();
            //Log.d("THE DATA IS ", "+ data.get(i)");

           /* for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
            {
                tv.setText(data.get(i).toString());
                Log.d("hi","data[i]");
            }*/
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to modify this code so that I can get retrieved values from the database

Comment: Can you specify a bit better what isn't working?

Comment: I want to get values of the coordinates stored in arraylist or any other data structure and want to show them in a text view by retrieving them from the database

Comment: I have added getdata function in database.java which is using arraylist but it is not storing anything in arraylist