# How to display coordinates of the screen when touched stored in arraylist to display it in text View

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am making an app which when clicked on the screen stores the coordinates in Database and after that I am retrieving it from Database in the form of arraylist but I am only getting the last coordinate y in the textview because I am making only one textview so can anyone tell how to display all the coordinates on the screen.

for my  code please see this link 
[How to store coordinates of the screen in Database and how to retrieve all of them when clicked on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533575/how-to-store-coordinates-of-the-screen-in-database-and-how-to-retrieve-all-of-th)

Comment: I don't really get your question...do you want to concatenate all coordinates to one string? Is your question how to concatenate strings?

Comment: I want to display the coordinates on the screen

Comment: Then you could just put all coordinates together in one string, couldn't you?

Comment: I think you have not seen the code I have stored all the coordinates in the arraylist

Comment: Then you make a loop to get the coordinates out of the ArrayList...please post your code

Comment: I have posted the code have you clicked on the link